# Kotlin - if statement not working properly

Tags: kotlin

I have this very simple code:

```
    var i = 1

    if(i  < 5)
     button.setOnClickListener{
        i++
     }
```

but when i is equal to 5, it still enter into the if and i increases and I have no idea on why it do that.

Comment: you mean when `var i = 5`, it still go to `if` ?

Comment: yeah, when i == 5 still go in if

Comment: What you actually wanted to achieve? Why putting `onClickListener` in if statement?

Comment: when i == 5 then it should not enter in the if, where is a code to start an animation. But even with only i++, it still goes in if

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `i` is less than `5` this code:

```
if(i  < 5)
 button.setOnClickListener{
    i++
 }
```

sets the listener for `button`.
If later `i` changes its value to something `>=5` **the listener is still valid**, so every time you click on the button `i` will be incremented.
So if you want to cancel the listener you can do:

```
if (i >= 5) button.setOnClickListener(null)
```